# Execute CGI scripts on custom OMAP4 board as root

Tags: networking, cgi

I have a Ubuntu 12.04 Custom Board running Apache2. I have a web page which calls a CGI script which is responsible for starting and stopping ipsec service. I access the web page from another machine in local environment. Following is the CGI script that gets called when I press a simple button in UI:

```
root@localhost:~# busybox cat /usr/lib/cgi-bin/stop-IPSec.cgi 
#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
echo "<html><head><title>Configure IP Address"
echo "</title></head><body>"
echo $(whoami)
echo $(/etc/init.d/ipsec stop)
echo $(su root /etc/init.d/ipsec stop)
echo "</body></html>"
```

Gives me output:

```
www-data ipsec_setup: permission denied (must be superuser)
```

And the following line fails:

```
echo $(su root /etc/init.d/ipsec stop)
```

And gives this error in apache error log:

```
su: must be run from a terminal
```

And `sudo` is not available since I am running Ubuntu Core on board which I intent to use as Wifi Dongle.
I want to stop ipsec service and that requires it to be root. How can this be achieved. Any pointers will make my day.

Comment: `chmod u+s` <-- look into it.

Comment: @Chris: no change on `chmod u+s /usr/lib/cgi-bin/stopIPSec.cgi`
I have not created any virtual site as in my HTML pages are in `/var/www/` folder, could this be an issue?

Comment: I have learned that I can exploit IPC Mechanism and make a script listening as a server and the cgi scripts can call that scripts as clients to execute actual shell commands.
For Example I can call startIPSec from my cgi script and the receiving script can execute actual ipsec start which requires the user to be superuser. Only thing is I have to run that listening script with superuser permissions and I have no experience in writing such scripts. Please let me know if this makes sense and if there are any links explaining this concept with example.